# bareboxenv-target: script not found

Tags: embedded-linux, target, environment, bootloader

I'm working with ptxdist, with barebox as a bootloader.

I'm trying to use 'bareboxenv' script in my arm to save the barebox environment to a file, so I've set the option which allows to compile it for arm in 'barebox.make' and tried to compiled again ptxdist.
The problem is that ptxdist asks for a script called 'bareboxenv-target', which should be in scripts directory, but it isn't there.
I've used

```
find . -name bareboxenv-target
```

to look for it from my home directory. Not found.

Also I've looked for it online:  https://gitorious.org/oselas/ptxdist/source/668c3e0634ab68c7fdccff1fe9ca1bf546a4ce87:scripts
but it isn't there either.
Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: I just wanted to follow up and see if any of my solutions below worked for you. Is there anything I should add/subtract from my answer to make it acceptable. If not, feel free to click the check mark to approve the answer so others will know the solution is valid. Hope it all worked out for you!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the version of barebox that is used in ptxdist is not compatible with bareboxenv-target.

I cannot say why PTXDist would enable a feature and not update the source to support it. It appears to be a bug. [There is an explanation here](http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/4913#27659).

You could try updating the Barebox installation version by:

1. Updating the make file to include a new archive of source
2. Updating the make file to include a new md5 sum.
3. Update any patch files associated with barebox (This is the hard part).
4. Rebuilding PTXDist and verifying it works.

Personally, I think this might be a long bunny trail and I am not going down that path unless I find a good reason to do so. Best of luck!